# Could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2. Is libxml2 installed? error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, gcc, python-imaging-library

I'm on my way to deploy, and using elastic beanstalk. When I do eb create, I'm getting your requirements.txt is invalid and when I looked closer I was getting two errors

```
  Could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2. Is libxml2 installed?
  *********************************************************************************
  error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

I don't know what I could possibly do more, I tried 
uninstalling pillow 
then `sudo apt-get install libjpeg-dev`
the install `pillow` back
and `pip install lxml`

I tried

```
sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev python-dev
```

and

```
apt-get install libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev python-dev
```

I just want to deploy what I have but this pillow thing is grabbing my ankle can you please help me

Do I need to anything here maybe?

```
    packages:
      yum:
        git: []
        postgresql93-devel: []
        libjpeg-turbo-devel: []
        libpng-devel: []
        freetype-devel: []


container_commands:
  01_migrate:
    command: "source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && python ebagu/manage.py migrate --noinput"
    leader_only: true
  02_createsu:
    command: "source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && python ebagu/manage.py createsu"
    leader_only: true
  03_collectstatic:
    command: "source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && python ebagu/manage.py collectstatic --noinput"
  04_uninstall_pil:
    command: "source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && yes | pip uninstall Pillow"

  05_reinstall_pil:
    command: "source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && yes | pip install Pillow --no-cache-dir"


option_settings:
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment":
    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: "app.settings"
    "PYTHONPATH": "/opt/python/current/app/app:$PYTHONPATH"
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python":
    WSGIPath: app/app/wsgi.py
    NumProcesses: 3
    NumThreads: 20
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:staticfiles":
    "/static/": "www/static/"
```

Comment: Installing `libxml2-dev` solved this error for me.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon's elastic beanstalk does not currently support the apt-get package manager, so the default `yum` must be used as seen in your config file. You could manually install pillow's dependencies if you were to ssh into the server using

```
sudo yum install libxml2-devel libxslt-devel libjpeg-turbo-devel
```

(also note the different package names). Or preferably as additions to your config file so they are installed as needed on deployment.

```
packages:
  yum:
     # Your other non-python packages
    libxml2-devel: []
    libxslt-devel: []
    libjpeg-turbo-devel: []
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this for Ubuntu:

```
   sudo apt-get install -y libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev zlib1g-dev python3-pip
```

Comment: Works for Debian as well.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the exact same error when trying to install `lxml` in an EC2 instance deployed using Elastic Beanstalk (AMI 2017.03), just like in the original question. The problem occurred only with Python 3.5, with Python 2.7 I could install it without trouble.

In my case, the problem was that GCC was not installed. Doing `sudo yum install gcc` solved it.

I think the problem is that Amazon AMI repositories do not contain the binary package of the Python 3 bindings for libxml2. The bindings for Python 2.6 and 2.7 (`python2X-lxml`) are available, that's why everything works out of the box with Python 2. But when using `pip-3.5`, pip does not find them and tries instead to install them from source, at which point it needs GCC.

The `packages` section of my elastic beanstalk configuration file looks like this:

```
packages:
    yum:
        gcc: []
        python35: []
        python35-pip: []
        python35-devel: []
        libxml2-devel: []
        libxslt-devel: []
```